# How to checkin using share dialog with facebook apiv2.2?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to checkin on facebook using share open graph dialog with placeid as parameter.What should be the supported action_type?

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share_open_graph?
 app_id="+ FACEBOOK_APP_ID + "&display=popup&action_type="+ "
 &action_properties={place:" + FACEBOOK_PLACE_ID + "}&redirect_uri="+ WEB_URL
```

Currently i am using graph api for checkin with me/feed as url and place as parameter which requires publish_action permission but facebook is not approving my publish_action permission so i wanted to switch to share open graph dialog but not getting supported action type.

Comment: Did you already solve this, I badly want to know